# How to set Timeout for a mysql query in Java?

Tags: mysql, timeout

I want to set some timeout for a mysql query to execute in java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using [`Statement.setQueryTimeout`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#setQueryTimeout(int))?